# react bootstrap position of elements not working

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

This question is about React Bootstrap Navbar Responsive navbar.

I have created react app and import react-bootstrap bootstrap in it. I am trying to create nav bar using bootstrap but it is not working. Trying to create  navbar dark but all element are placing next to each other . There is no padding. I am placing brand name in the left and other pages in the right. I am making it responsive . If click on menu bar all links to be appear but it is not showing links. Using media queries I gave some padding so that links will be in center. How to make it responsive ? Please explain in detail.

I think I have imported all required files.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This link need to be import in every page where I am using bootstrap ?

Like home page I have created other pages (Contact, About) also (not included here).

**App.js**

```
    import './App.css';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Link,Navbar,NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
    import Home from "./Home";
    import About from "./About"
    import Connection from "./Connection";
    import Contact from "./Contact";
    import Projects from "./Projects";
    // import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    function App() {
     
      return (
        <Router>
        <div className="container"> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
      <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-right">
    
          <li className="nav-item active"><Link to="/">
            Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> </Link>
          </li>
    
          <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/about"> About </Link>
          </li>
    
          <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/connection"> Connection </Link>
          </li>
    
          <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/projects"> Projects </Link>
          </li>
    
          <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/contact"> Contact </Link>
          </li> 
    
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav> 
    
        <Switch>
        <Route path= "/" exact component = {Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component = {About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component = {Contact} />
        <Route path="/connection" component = {Connection} />
        <Route path="/projects" component = {Projects} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
    @media(max-width:568px){
      li{
           padding-left: 42%;
       }
    }
```

**Home.js**

```
    import './App.css';
    import React from 'react';
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    // import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    
    function Home(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>This is Home Page !</h1>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
    export default Home;
```

Comment: just added className instead of class

Comment: You missed a few in app.js. <nav> element has class instead of className.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: ``` <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>``` The class needs to changed to className